# Use of form structure inside jQuery accordion on Google App Scripts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-apps-script

I am using a form inside an accordion structure (jQueryUI), on the HTML Services in Google App Script. And the form structure looks something like this:

[image: Accordion with form on HtmlService]

[image: Accordion with form on HtmlService]

And the relevant code is as follows:

```
    <div id="accordion">
    <h3 id='academic-information'>
       <a href='#'>
            <label><input class='header-checkbox' type='checkbox' />Academic Information</label>
      </a>
    </h3>
    <div>
    <form id='calcForm'>
      <label>Choose from a Student Type: </label><br />
    <input name = "stateTuition" type="radio" id = 'sTuition' value='0'/>Resident Student<br />
    <input name = "stateTuition" type="radio" id = 'sTuition' value ='1'/>Non-Resident Student<br />
      <br /><br />
      <label>Stipulated period of Education :</label><br />
      <input name = "academicTrack" type="radio" id = "aTrack" value='0' />4 Years - 15 cr./semester<br />
     <input name = "academicTrack" type="radio" id = "aTrack" value='1' />5 Years - 12 cr./semester<br />
     <input name = "academicTrack" type="radio" id = "aTrack" value='2' />6 Years - 10 cr./semester<br />
     <input name = "academicTrack" type="radio" id = "aTrack" value='3' />7 Years - Non-Traditional<br />
     <input name = "academicTrack" type="radio" id = "aTrack" value='4' />8 Years - Non-Traditional<br />
      </form>
    </div>
    <h3 id='campus-housing'>
        <a href='#'>
            <label><input class='header-checkbox' type='checkbox' />Campus Housing</label>
        </a>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <form id='calcForm'>
        <label>What is the nature of Housing Plan you wish to subscribe: </label><br />
        <input name = "housingType" type="radio" id = "hType" value='0' />No Housing<br />
   <input name = "housingType" type="radio" id = "hType" value='1' />Dorm<br />
 <input name = "housingType" type="radio" id = "hType" value='2' />Apartment<br />
        <br /><br />
        <label>Choose from a room type of your desire: </label><br />
         <input name = "roomType" type="radio" id = "rType" value='0' />No Housing<br />
     <input name = "roomType" type="radio" id = "rType" value='1' />Single Occupancy Room<br />
     <input name = "roomType" type="radio" id = "rType" value='2' />Double Occupancy Room<br />
     <input name = "roomType" type="radio" id = "rType" value='3' />Single Occupancy - Double Room<br /> 
        <br /><br />
      </form>
    </div>
    <h3 id='other-info'>
        <a href='#'>
            <label><input class='header-checkbox' type='checkbox' />Miscellaneous Information</label>
        </a>
    </h3>
    <div>
    <form id='calcForm'>
      <label>Subscription to On-Campus meal plans:</label><br />
      <input name = "campusMealPlan" type="radio" id = 'mPlan' value='0' />No Meal Plan<br />
     <input name = "campusMealPlan" type="radio" id = 'mPlan' value ='1' />Gold Plan 1<br />
 <input name = "campusMealPlan" type="radio" id = 'mPlan' value ='2' />Gold Plan 2<br />
 <input name = "campusMealPlan" type="radio" id = 'mPlan' value ='3' />Silver Plan 1<br />
 <input name = "campusMealPlan" type="radio" id = 'mPlan' value ='4' />Silver Plan 2<br />    
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
 <form id='calcForm'>
  <input type="button" value="Project Cost" onclick = 'google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(processCost).processForm(this.parentNode)'/>
</form>
```

Everything works fine except for, google.script.run which executes processForm is not able to pass all the values associated with form 'calcForm'. I am assuming it is because the form is broken between the div's. What is the solution to this, in other words how can I send in all the information collected through the form in the accordion to processForm function on clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't break up a form that way. Why not just wrap the entire code in a single form with all the divs and jquery stuff inside of it?

Comment: Ok so that works, and the fact is I had tried it before. But earlier I was trying to open the form below the "accordion" div and close before closing the accordion div, which doesn't work, because it distorts the accordion somehow. But I just place the form tag opening and closing outside the "accordion" div opening and closing and it works. Thanks Corey.

Comment: So, perhaps you cannot break up a form that way, but what about if each form is named differently? Can that work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I actually made it by wrapping the form inside divs